# Nested Objects in GraphQL Schema in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphql

I'm creating a GraphQL Server using Node JS.

I'm trying to replicate the mongo Schema which has a nested object purely for organisation. This is my mongo schema:

```
  var plansSchema = new Schema({
  planName:  {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Plan name is required"]
  },
  pricing: {
    monthly: Number,
    scanEnvelope: Number,
    initalScan: Number,
    perPage: Number,
    forwardMail: Number,
    forwardParcel: Number,
    shred: Number,
    perMonthPerGram: Number,
    freeStorePerGram: Number,
    setup: Number,
    idFree: Number
  },
  expires: Number,
  private: Boolean,
  deleted: Boolean,
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
```

I'm trying to replicate this in a GraphQL schema, so far I have the following:

```
const PlanType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Plan",
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLString },
    planName: { type: GraphQLString },
    pricing: new GraphQLObjectType({
      name: "Pricing",
      fields: () => ({
        expires: { type: GraphQLInt },
        private: { type: GraphQLBoolean },
        monthly: { type: GraphQLInt },
        scanEnvelope: { type: GraphQLInt },
        initalScan: { type: GraphQLInt },
        perPage: { type: GraphQLInt },
        forwardMail: { type: GraphQLInt },
        forwardParcel: { type: GraphQLInt },
        shred: { type: GraphQLInt },
        perMonthPerGram: { type: GraphQLInt },
        freeStorePerGram: { type: GraphQLInt },
        setup: { type: GraphQLInt },
        idFree: { type: GraphQLInt }
      })
    })
  })
});
```

But I'm getting the following errro in GraphiQL

```
   {
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "The type of Plan.pricing must be Output Type but got: undefined."
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, please how do you perform the add mutation for the Plan type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each field in the `GraphQLFieldConfigMapThunk` or `GraphQLFieldConfigMap` that you set as your `fields` must be a `GraphQLFieldConfig` object that includes properties like `type`, `args`, `resolve`, etc. You cannot set a `field` to a `GraphQLObjectType` like you're doing with the `pricing` field. In other words, your code should look more like this:

```
const PricingType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Pricing",
  fields: () => ({
    expires: { type: GraphQLInt },
    private: { type: GraphQLBoolean },
    monthly: { type: GraphQLInt },
    scanEnvelope: { type: GraphQLInt },
    initalScan: { type: GraphQLInt },
    perPage: { type: GraphQLInt },
    forwardMail: { type: GraphQLInt },
    forwardParcel: { type: GraphQLInt },
    shred: { type: GraphQLInt },
    perMonthPerGram: { type: GraphQLInt },
    freeStorePerGram: { type: GraphQLInt },
    setup: { type: GraphQLInt },
    idFree: { type: GraphQLInt }
  })
})

const PlanType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Plan",
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLString },
    planName: { type: GraphQLString },
    pricing: { type: PricingType },
  }),
})
```